# Query para comprobar si existe empresa con mismo código

Tags: php, mysql, poo, pdo

Estoy intentado hacer una funcion en PDO, POO y AJAX para comprobar si existe una empresa en la base de datos con el mismo código introducido en el formulario y en caso afirmativo permitir el registro y en caso negativo no permitirlo.

El formulario sería este:

```
<form id="verificarafiliacion" method="post" onSubmit="return checkSubmit();">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"> # </span>
                      <input name="codafi" type="text" class="form-control form-ofit" placeholder="Código de Afiliación" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12"><div id="result" style="padding:20px;"></div></div>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <button class="ofit-btn btsubmit" id="verificarempresa" type="submit">Verificar Código</button>
          </form>
```

La función de la clase es esta:

```
    public function validateCompany($codigo) {

        $check = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM empresas WHERE Codigo = '$codigo'");
        $check->execute();
        $rows = $check->fetchColumn();

        if ($rows == "1") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Por otro lado, el controlador es este:

```
$class = new User;

if (isset($_POST['codafi'])) {

    $cod = secure($_POST['codafi']);
    $class->validateCompany($cod);

    if ($class == true) {
        echo "Empresa encontrada";
    } else {
        echo "empresa no encontrada";
    }

}
```

Y el código ajax es este:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#verificarafiliacion', function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({            
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'assets/controllers/checkcodigo.php',
        data : data,
        success :  function(data) {
            debugger;
            $("#result").html(data).fadeIn();
        },
        complete: function(){
           setTimeout(function() {
           }, 15000);    
        }
    });
    debugger;
    return false;
});
```

No sé que estoy haciendo mal pero siempre me devuelve true...

¿Alguien sabría decirme que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Hola, tal vez deberías cambiar `if ($rows == "1") {`por `if ($rows > 0) {` , puede que ese sea el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema esta en el controlador, hasta donde yo tengo conocimiento, lo unico que tendrias que verificar es el resultado de la funcion y no la instancia de la clase, de la siguiente manera:

```
if ($class->validateCompany($cod)) {
    //permitir registro
} else {
    //no permitir
}
```

Espero esto te ayude

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la pregunta para hacerlo con ajax. Perdona por no formular la pregunta con ajax desde el principio...

Comment: ya actualice la respuesta

Comment: Era eso, ahora funciona perfectamente!! Muchas gracias!